# Android список с добавление элементов

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, список

День добрый, подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать следующее на языке Java для Android:

1. У меня есть item.xml(дата, кол-вы, стоимость, модель), который будет выступать в качестве элемента списка
2. Изначально в список добавляется только один элемент
3. На MainActivity будет присутствовать список и две кнопки(по нажатию на кнопку "Добавить" создаётся ещё один элемент списка item.xml, на кнопку "Сохранить" - эти все введенные данные сохраняются в БД и активность обновляется, убираются все заполненные данные и элементы списка, чтоб остался только один пустой, для дальнейшего заполнения).

Буду благодарен за помощь

P.S. возможно ли это реализовать с помощью RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

Решение достаточно простое. Вам нужен RecyclerView. Вы сделаете адаптер и вьюхолдер. С помощью адаптера будете управлять содержимым списка, а с помощью вьюходеров - отображать ячейки.
я бы привел пример, но stackoverflow не разрешает ссылки на ресурсы конкурентов)) но ничего гуглиться это легко